# elegant way to print "==== middle justified title ====" in python

Tags: python

As I know, there are some elegant ways to print left and right justified string with filling.
like this

```
str = "left_justified"
str.ljust(20, '0');
```

or

```
print "{0:{1}<20}".format(str, "=")
```

result will be

```
left_justified=====
```

what is the best way to print middle-justified string with filling

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> "hello".center(50, '=')
'======================hello======================='
```

Answer (score 5):

You missed the `^`:

```
s = 'centered'
print "{0:{1}^20}".format(s, "=")
# -> ======centered======
```

I have also taken the liberty of renaming your `str` variable to something that doesn't shadow the built-in `str`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> termwidth, fillchar = 78, '='
>>> print ' middle justified title '.center(termwidth, fillchar)
=========================== middle justified title ===========================
```